# Android xml grammar

Tags: android, xml

I came across a piece of code like this:

```
<android:TextClock
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I know that `android` is an xml name space, so the code indicates that `TextClock` is an attribute defined in `android` name space or something else?

And why if I wrote something like this, it's an error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your root view android must be imported like below

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: And your api level must be above 17. Set your minSdkVersion 17 in app build.Gradle file

Comment: Of course, the root view was imported. I just wonder why can I wrote something like this, and why the error pops up. Thank you for you answer.